Start a stopped Docker Compose container
Is it possible just to start a single container among a group of stopped Docker Compose container?
I have a docker-compose.yml file that contains 4 containers: redis, postgres, api and worker. If all of them has stopped, can I start just one of them to check the config files within it? I'm getting
you cannot start and attach multiple containers at once
and I'm wondering if there is any way to work around it.

What command line did you execute to get the error message?

The standard one @Jib, docker star -ai api-container.

I'd just do docker run -it api bash so as to get the container to not do its normal thing, and then you can use the resulting shell to explore the filing system. (Whether this is the right solution depends on how much config in the DC YAML file you need in order to start the container at all.)

If we want to just start the stopped container: docker start <container-id-or-name>. To get an interactive shell to said container, we can run docker exec -it <container-name-or-id> /bin/bash (or ... /bin/sh, depending on what is available in the container).

Another way would be to docker export  (docs.docker.com) the file system of the container.

Hmm.., good idea @halfer, I gave it a try but quickly gave up -- docker compose is there for a reason, I totally agree with you, it'll work for simple cases but it really depends on how much config in the DC YAML file needed in order to start the container. I was thinking to take a short cut, but after trying it, I realize that running docker compose IS the short cut. So, basically, I stop trying -- it's a bad idea. Thanks for your answers, everyone!

In that case, you can temporarily change the DC YAML file for this container so that it has a command of /bin/bash, then do docker compose up {service}. You may need to exec onto the running container, but at least Bash should stop it exiting. You may need to add interactive and terminal flags in the YAML too.

You can run a single container with command
docker compose start <service-name>


Note: it won't work if your service/container are depends on another
service/container.

If you want to check the config files within it, you could just run
docker compose run -it <service-name> sh


Note: it will create and running a new container.

Another way to do it is by copying the config file directly without running the stopped container with this command
docker compose cp <service-name>:<config-file-path> <destination>


It's hard to exactly answer your question without an mvp compose file that gets the error you want. But you don't need to start the container to look at a config file in it.
Look at the docker mount, unmount, cp, and export commands.

Accessing the container file system is exactly what those commands do. Do you mean the config file could reside somewhere other than the container file system? I mean, they could, but the question specifically says "config files within it" so presumably they aren't installed in a volume or remote filesystem or anything. I mean, I assuming the question asker meant what they said . . .

No, i overread the export part, which is probably the most useful command in the given scenario :) My comment will self-destruct shortly.
